# how to use highcharts tooltip formatter in python code

Tags: python, highcharts

I am using django chartit  for drawing line charts. I am trying to set up the whole highcharts data within my python code. I got chart options like x-Axis title ,y-Axis as dictionaries in my python code, am able to get the chart.

Now, I need to use tooltip formatter to give custom values when hover a point. I modified the data as needed for formatter. But , how can I use below code in python which is java script,

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
             return this.<mydata> ;
                              }
              }
```

Any help appreciable.

Comment: The question is - could you get this data earlier? I think it will be better idea to get this data before you will make your chart and add it to your point (for example as pointFormat parametr). Then you will be able to get all of necessary information in your tooltip using return this.options.pointFormat. If you would like to get your data every time you are hovering your point,  return this.<mydata> may not be the most sufficient way of making your chart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. we can use  only point.x ,point.y ,series.name ans series.color with pointFormat .But I want to show more values which are in my data like,
data : [ {'y': 10, 'temp': abcd} , 
             {'y':20, 'temp' : xyz }
 along with x, y values. How can I access 'temp' values to show in point?
I can show with 'this.<my data>' . Problem here we don't have 'this' in python

Comment: I think it is possible to show more values using pointFormatter. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/8rpem4g0/

Comment: We need to pass as functions to pointFormatter or formatter which is javascript code the one I pasted. How can I give that in my python script?
function(), return , this are not defined in python , right.

Comment: After lot of trials, I have given like ,
 'pointFormat': "name:   <b>{point.name}</b><br/> value:   <b>{point.y}</b><br/>"
instead of function. It Worked!!.
Thanks a lot for giving 'pointFormat' idea.

Answer (score -1):

Try to wrap the function in quotes like in this example:

```
'labels': {
            'formatter': "function () {\
                return this.value + '°';\
            }"
        },
```